# how to select specific values from table

Tags: t-sql

Well I've thought that will be a easy query , but found out it's not.
Straight to point.
Let's say I have following table named MyTable:

```
| ID        | Val1       | Val2       | GroupName
--------------------------------------------------
|         1 |          1 | null       | GroupA
|         2 |          2 | 1          | GroupA
|         3 |          3 | 2          | GroupA
|         4 |          4 | 3          | GroupA
|         5 |          1 |            | GroupB
|         6 |          2 | 1          | GroupB
|         7 |          3 | 2          | GroupB
|         8 |          2 | 1          | GroupC
|         9 |          3 | 2          | GroupC
|        10 |          4 | 3          | GroupC
|        11 |          5 | 4          | GroupC
```

Unfortunatelly Val1,Val2 and GroupName are strings.

What I'd like to achieve is result like

```
SELECT T.GroupName FROM Mytable T WHERE T.GroupName NOT IN
(
    SELECT T2.GroupName FROM Mytable T2 
    WHERE T2.Val2 IS NULL OR LEN(T2.Val2)=0
)
GROUP BY T.GroupName
```

So basically I'd like to get all rows where data grouped around specyfic GroupName column   there is not case like GroupC where we don't have in Val2 null or empty. Empty or null is required to pass.

Val1 and Val2 are related and enclosed with the same GroupName:

example

Val2  with Id=3 is actually taken from the same table with ID=2 for GroupA

So my finall result would be :

```
|GroupName
------------
|GroupC
```

How to query that correctly?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but what's wrong with the query you shared?

Comment: Yeap, looks fine, right? However it returns nothing while should find GroupA and GroupB. GroupC should be skipped. BTW: GroupName column is varchar(300).

Comment: So I'm assuming then that the subquery returns nothing if you run it by itself: `SELECT T2.GroupName FROM Mytable T2 
    WHERE T2.Val2 IS NULL OR LEN(T2.Val2)=0` Are you certain about your data?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I have updated post. I'm expecting GroupC :)Subquery returns A &B so main select should find only C

Comment: And yes, I'm sure about my data.

Comment: Your query should work. Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017?

Answer (score 0):

JNavil you were right - data issue. In a few thousands of records one of them had null value inside GroupName. Thank you bro!